# Архитектура Vue приложения

Tags: vue.js, архитектура, vue-router

Нуждаюсь в правильном совете по организации приложения. Пишу на vue+vuetify, взял за основу проект с [github](https://github.com/jjdelarosa/laravelspa). В моем приложении есть три типа страниц. Первая страница простая, содержит навигационную панель и при клике на пункты меню меняется содержимое страницы. Тут все просто, используя vue-router можно менять содержимое страницы.

[image: Вариант страницы 1]

Но есть второй вариант, более сложный. При клике на этот тип страницы, открывается вариант страницы с сайдабаром, то есть кликаем на элементы сайдбара, меняется содержимое окошка справа. И тут я уже не знаю что делать, получается что vue-router в vue-router, но как приложению понять какой из роутеров надо открыть?

[image: Вариант страницы 2]

И есть вариант страницы 3. В сайдбар добавляются ещё и вкладки, и содержимое сайдбара меняется от выбранной вкладки. В тоже время в меню справа грузится либо что-то от выбранного во вкладке, либо что-то что назначено в Menu 1. То есть получается и для сайдбара vue-router и для содержимого вкладок и для окна справа, как в них не запутаться то...

[image: Вариант страницы 3]

Приложение для организации путешествий, отелей, и т.д.. Как правило в окне справа будет гугл карта, но не всегда. В некоторых случаях будет другой контент.

Надеюсь все объяснил правильно. Помогите пожалуйста советом и если можно кусками кода, как сделать такой функционал приложения? Спасибо.

Comment: [Релевантная статья](https://itnext.io/anyway-heres-how-to-create-a-multiple-layout-system-with-vue-and-vue-router-b379baa91a05) (правда на английском)